# Powershell - Retrieve Count from SQLPlus query

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm working with a powershell script which utilizes SQLPlus to query an oracle database.

The Query is: `select count(*) from table`

The powershell query outputs:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Sat Feb 6 09:50:52 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Testing options


  COUNT(*)
----------
    50

Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
```

I'm currently using the statement below to retrieve the Count, though it seems to not be capturing the result.

```
if($file -match 'count (?<count>\d+)'){$count=[int32]$matches['count']}
```

Any help/guidance would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: What is the type of `$file`? `$file.GetType().Fullname`. Your query is not accounting for the multi-line nature of this. Also the number does not appear right after the count which is why it is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see one problem and a potential issue. The latter being I suspect `$file` is a string array. That works against you since you are looking for a number based on the presence of text a couple lines above.

The problem is your regex is not multi-line and in your sample the number does not appear on the same line as count. Your regex would only match `Count 50`. That is not how it appear in the text you show.

Two ensure both points lets make `$file` one single string and then run a multi-line regex that matches the first number encountered after "COUNT". Keep the named match logic you have as it is nice to have.

```
# This can most likely be moved to where this is read in.
$file = $file | Out-String

# try and match the regex. 
if($file -match "(?s)Count.*?(?<count>\d+)"){
    [int32]$Matches.Count
}
```

Comment: Hello @Matt, thanks again for the help!
So, $file is being read from a .txt file which contains a result from a SQLPlus call. The type of $file is "System.String"

`$file = Get-Content -path $filepath | out-string`

The solution is also working many thanks!
Your match string was correct

Comment: @StephenSugumar I figured as much since that is something I think I helped you with. However I couldn't see that in this post so I answered ignoring that likely possibility.